# Ошибка при создании constexpr-объекта собственного типа

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, компиляция, constexpr

В следующем коде - ошибка компиляции:

```
template <typename T, size_t N = 1u>
class array
{
public:
    constexpr array(std::initializer_list<T> il) noexcept
    {
        for (auto i = 0u; i < il.size(); ++i)
        {
            m_array[i] = il.begin()[i];
        }
    }
private:
    T m_array[N];
    size_t m_size = N;
};
constexpr array<int> m_arr = { 1 };
```

В примере приведена только проблемная часть кода(часть шаблона и создание constexpr-объекта). Проблема в инициализации constexpr-объекта через этот конструктор, но если его создавать не как constexpr, то все работает корректно. Разные компиляторы дают разные ошибки из-за этого конструктора. В чем может быть проблема?
Видел эту проблему на англо-язычном стэке, но ответ не дал ясности.

Comment: На будущее: стоит явно приводить ошибки компиляции прямо в вопросе. Ссылка на соседние стеки также не возбранялась бы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

До C++20 `constexpr`-конструктор должен явно инициализировать все нестатические члены класса ([dcl.constexpr/4.5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.constexpr#4.5)) . При этом это можно сделать как в списке инициализации:

```
constexpr array(std::initializer_list<T> il) noexcept
   :m_array{} {/*...*/}
```

Так и при объявлении члена:

```
T m_array[N] = {};
```

---

В С++20 это требование убрали и код из вопроса должен компилироваться «как есть».

Comment: Кстати, а как должен отреагировать компилятор, если `N` не будет соответствовать `il.size()`? Это не к тому, что у вас что-то в ответе неверно, просто глянул на код — и подумалось, а как бы `N` получать из `il.size()`, все равно он должен быть именно таким?...

Comment: Я знаю об этой небольшой проблеме. Пока только пришло такое решение: в списке инициализации этого конструктора добавить m_size(il.size()). Это может быть как подстраховка, если при создании объекта будет указан отличный размер.

Comment: @Harry, если больше `N`, то для `constexpr`'а должна быть ошибка... для времени выполнения — UB... из `std::initializer_list` шаблон ни как вывести не получится, так что с ним ни от `N` ни избавится, ни проверку времени компиляции не сделать... в качестве альтернативы вот [пара идей](https://godbolt.org/z/W6aExEYcq)... `carray` подсмотрен [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438671/static-assert-on-initializer-listsize), а `sarray` — в `std::array`... ЗЫ: `m_size` — в принципе лишний член...

Comment: @Fat-Zer Вот и получается избыточность — надо N указать, причем указать верно...

Comment: @Harry... нуда... издержки плюсов... можно инициализировать ссылкой на массив как с `carray` в «идеях» выше...